# Author-year citation with self-generated Natbib-Style, Lyx

Tags: bibtex, lyx, natbib

I have generated a bib-style for Lyx using the terminal (bib.bst) and am using it in Lyx 2.0.3 with JabRef, natbib and author-year citation. Everything works great, only now in citations I don't get only the author's last but also the first names, which is far too long. Is there a way to change this?

Thanks a lot, I'm not very experienced and would be glad about help! (sorry, not even sure whether that's bibtex or biblatex. A friend helped me there.)